# Start/Restart script when switching to other tab

Tags: javascript, youtube, firefox-addon

You know those pesky anti-adblock Youtube pop-up ? Well, I'm developping a Firefox extension to remove them automatically as soon as they appear (I call it Youtube AdBlock-Block-Block).
It's pretty simple : The script waits until the element called "YTD-POPUP-CONTAINER" appears, then removes it. It only works when not connected, but it's a start.
However, I'm still an amateur, so of course it's far from perfect. I'm trying to improve it step by step.

One of the biggest issues is that the pop-up only appears when the page loads completely. And when you open a video in a new tab WITHOUT switching to that tab, the page apparently doesn't fully load until you've switched to it. Or so it seems.

So I would like my script to start (or restart) when I switch to that new tab.
Or, alternatively, to make my script re-check regularly if the pop-up has appeared (but I'm worried it might be too taxing on the CPU).

In case it helps, here's the manifest code :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Youtube AdBlock-Block-Block",
    "version": "1.1",

  
    "description": "Automatically removes the Youtube pop-up when you're using an Adblocker",


    "icons": {
      "48": "icons/Icon_48.png",
      "96": "icons/Icon_96.png"
      },
  
  
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
        "js": ["ytabbb.js"]
      }
    ]
    
  }
```

And here's the script code (ytabbb.js) :

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                observer.disconnect();
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}


waitForElm("YTD-POPUP-CONTAINER").then((elm) => {
    console.log('Element is ready');
    console.log(elm.textContent);
});

const element = document.getElementsByTagName("YTD-POPUP-CONTAINER");

while(element.length > 0){
    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
}
```

I looked for tutorials on how to achieve what I described, but I haven't found one that seemed to 'cleanly' match what I need.

...

*EDIT : Nevermind, I asked ChatGPT and he came up with this :*

```
/* initial script logic here */

function restartScript() {
    /* script logic to be repeated here */

    console.log('Script restarted on tab switch!');
}

// Listen for tab switch or focus events
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
        // Tab is visible, restart the script
        restartScript();

    }
});
```

*It seems to be working pretty well so far.*